# Mule app deploy failed - why?

Tags: deployment, mule

Hi I'm trying to redeploy a Mule app to a Mule standalone server without success.

The app has been running on the server before but now it fails all the time.

The mule log is attached below, can anyone help me out?

The version of Java is 1.7 on the Muleserver and it's running on Ubuntu.

Mule-LOG:

INFO  2016-10-31 17:52:59,189 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.module.launcher.ArtifactArchiveInstaller: Exploding a Mule artifact archive: file:/opt/mule-standalone-3.5.0/apps/cognosimp2_9.zip
INFO  2016-10-31 17:52:59,236 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ New app 'cognosimp2_9'                                   +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

## INFO  2016-10-31 17:52:59,237 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.module.launcher.MuleApplicationClassLoader: [cognosimp2_9] Loading the following jars:

file:/opt/mule-standalone-3.5.0/apps/cognosimp2_9/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.0.7.jar
file:/opt/mule-standalone-3.5.0/apps/cognosimp2_9/lib/flatpack-3.2.0.jar
file:/opt/mule-standalone-3.5.0/apps/cognosimp2_9/lib/jtds-1.3.0.jar
file:/opt/mule-standalone-3.5.0/apps/cognosimp2_9/lib/javacsv-2.0.jar
file:/opt/mule-standalone-3.5.0/apps/cognosimp2_9/lib/sqljdbc4.jar
file:/opt/mule-standalone-3.5.0/apps/cognosimp2_9/lib/mule-module-csv-1.4-RC1.jar

## file:/opt/mule-standalone-3.5.0/apps/cognosimp2_9/lib/json-20080701.jar

INFO  2016-10-31 17:52:59,237 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.module.launcher.log4j.ArtifactAwareRepositorySelector: Found logging config for application 'cognosimp2_9' at 'file:/opt/mule-standalone-3.5.0/conf/log4j.properties'
ERROR 2016-10-31 17:52:59,887 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Failed to deploy artifact 'cognosimp2_9', see below      +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: UnsupportedClassVersionError: ChangeDatabase : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:181)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:62)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:57)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:274)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:294)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:158)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:220)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:80)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:272)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.run(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:350)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178)
    at

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong. When I edited the deployment file in Anypoint Studio the IDE was configured to use Compiler 1.8 and JRE 1.7 but the Mule server only has 1.7. I changed the compiler to 1.8 and now it works. You have to change both compiler and JRE in the IDE to make it work with the Mule servers versions.

Comment: Java 1.7 has been EOLed in April 2015. Time to upgrade.